# Condition query with LIKE does not match an exact match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm using the following query to search for users:

```
  @users = User.find( :all,
                      :select => 'users.*',
                      :conditions => ["lower(fname) || ' ' || lower(lname) LIKE ?", '%'+"#{params[:q].downcase}"+'%'],
  )
```

This works great for examples like so:

```
Bob S find Bob Smith
Bob finds Bob Smith
```

Problem is

```
Bob Smith does not find Bob Smith
```

How can I get the query above to return an exact match? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is just plain wrong. First, '||' is not a concatenation operator. Second, the operator precedence makes it evaluated as:

```
(lower(fname)) || (' ') || (lower(lname) LIKE '%Bob Smith%')
```

which is not what you want. I guess you would like it:

```
concat(lower(fname), ' ', lower(lname)) LIKE '%Bob Smith%'
```

EDIT: So you can use:

```
@users = User.find( :all,
                  :select => 'users.*',
                  :conditions => ["concat(lower(fname), ' ', lower(lname)) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q].downcase}%"])
```

EDIT2: The above is wrong, I haven't noticed it was about Postgresql. There is a '||' concatenation operator in Postgres of course. I'm not deleting this post because of the comments below but don't use it please.

Comment: thanks, I'm getting all kinds of syntax errors - ":conditions => concat(lower(fname), ' ', lower(lname)) LIKE "#{params[:q].downcase}","

Comment: Is concat Postgresql friendly?

Comment: Thanks Jan but no luck. I had to change the ) to a ] at the end, and then it resulted in the error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  function concat(text, unknown, text) does not exist

Comment: Aah, Postgresql. My wrong, of course, ignore my advice, I thought it was Mysql.

Comment: Thanks I think all I need to understand is the % operator. It seems that prevents an exact match?

Comment: In the logs I see: "SELECT users.* FROM "users" WHERE (lower(fname) || ' ' || lower(lname) LIKE '%jeff bat%') LIMIT 25" and even though I have a user with fname: jeff and lname: bat it is not being returned